# How do you adjust the idle on a 1981 Suzuki GS 650 GL?

Tags: motorcycle, idle

I'm asking this for a friend, so if you need more details, I'll have to ask him.

He brought his bike with him when he moved, and with the elevation change, the idle isn't high enough. How can he adjust it, or what's an easy way to find out how to adjust it?

EDIT:
Found this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXAfG.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you answered your own question.  You just have to back the idle screw out until the desired rpm is reached.  If the idling is an issue then carbs may need to be tuned for the altitude.